# Get Grandchild Object Field Values from Parent Object

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql, grandchild

I'm a newbie at sales-force apex coding. I have 3 custom objects, **Location(Parent) -> Group(child) - > Meeting(grand child)**. All are related to each other through Master detail relationships. I am trying to get 2 field values from the earliest Meeting Record that belongs to the Location.

So far I managed to get the get 2 field values from the earliest Meeting Record that belongs to the Business Object.

```
public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 = [SELECT Name,
GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM    
Meeting__c WHERE Group__c =:id ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c ASC LIMIT 1];
```

I am trying to get the same information obtained from the above query but this time I want to **get the earliest Meeting (grand child) Record that belongs to the Group records (child) belonging to the Location Record** from the Location Object *(Parent object getting grandchild record field values)*

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try query as:

```
public List<Meeting__c> MeetingsList2 = [SELECT Name,
GPS_Meeting_Location__Latitude__s, GPS_Meeting_Location__Longitude__s FROM    
Meeting__c WHERE Group__c =:id AND Group__r.Location__c =:locationId 
ORDER BY Meeting_Date__c ASC LIMIT 1];
```

I assumed, there is a reference field to Location(**Location__c**) in Group object and you have Location record Id in variable **locationId**.
FYI- __r is used to traverse/access to parent fields for a custom object.